# Django model filter with "exact" IN operator

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to find all users who have exactly same tags like a particular category (exactly same tags and also same amount of tags assigned)

Something like...

```
category = Category.objects.first()
User.objects.filter(tags__in=category.tags.filter())
```

But this returns also users who share even only one tag with the category.

Models are

```
class User(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='users')


class Category(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='categories')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

Any solution appreciated.

Comment: @ManojTolagekar You seem to be suggesting a lot of edits that apply `code formatting` to random keywords. Please don't do that, see [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but will work probably.

Iterate over `User` queryset and filter them one by one. example:

```
category = Category.objects.first()
for tag in category.tags.all():
    qs = User.objects.filter(tags__id=tag.id)
```

Other one:

```
category = Category.objects.first()
tag_ids = category.tags.values_list("id", flat=True)

valid_users = []
for user in User.objects.all():
    user_tag_ids = user.tags.values_list("id", flat=True)
    if set(user_tag_ids) == set(tag_ids):
        valid_users.append(user)
```

Comment: Thank you. I mark it as a solution as it answers the question. On the other hand, my main point was to find high performing algorithm for 1+M records. I thought about it some more, and if I go further for performance, I would go in bitmask direction, like bit masking attributes. https://findnerd.com/list/view/Bitmask-Attributes-in-Rails/21215/ With them, we can store a multiple attributes in one integer and then easily compare them with equal operators.